# cv api job.execute - authentication method unknown

Tags: cli

When I enter "cv api job.execute --user=cronuser --cwd=/srv/www/html/wordpress"
I get following error message:
cronuser has admin priviledges in wordpress and civicrm.

Initialization Error

```
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )
[code] =&gt; -24
[message] =&gt; DB Error: connect failed
[mode] =&gt; 16
[debug_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]
[type] =&gt; DB_Error
[user_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]
[to_string] =&gt; [db_error: message=&quot;DB Error: connect failed&quot; code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix=&quot;&quot; info=&quot; [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]&quot;]

)
```

Initialization Error

```
Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => simpleHandler
)
```

```
[code] =&gt; -24
[message] =&gt; DB Error: connect failed
[mode] =&gt; 16
[debug_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]
[type] =&gt; DB_Error
[user_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]
[to_string] =&gt; [db_error: message=&quot;DB Error: connect failed&quot; code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix=&quot;&quot; info=&quot; [nativecode=The server requested authentication method unknown to the client]&quot;]
```

)

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026939/php-mysqli-connect-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-caching-sha2-pa ?

Comment: Thanks so much, your hint was great. I got it solved by changing the mysql user to the old auth method... https://dcblog.dev/mysql-80-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client

Answer (score 2):

Changed Method to cli-Method.
Changed Mysql Auth Method for civicrm Mysql user:

https://dcblog.dev/mysql-80-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client

error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
The solution is to change the default authentication method to mysql_native_password.

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';